# Compile directive template before it is added to scope in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have an AngularJS directive like so:

```
MyDirective = (myService) ->

  templateUrl: 'my-partial.html'

  compile: () ->
    pre: ($scope, $element, $attrs, $controller) ->
      $attrs.$observe 'myDirective', (name) ->
        success = (response) ->
          $scope.entries = response

        failure = () ->
          console.log "Failed to load data for #{name}"

        myService.loadData(name)
        .then success, failure

MyDirective.$inject = ['MyService']
```

And a partial:

```
<ul>
  <li data-ng-repeat="entry in entries">
    <img src="{{entry.url}}">
  </li>
</ul>
```

How can I compile the template, thus replacing `...src="{{entry.url}}"...` with the correct `src` for the image, before it is added to the DOM?

The issue is that we get a number of 404 errors before the async call has received data and we want to avoid those.

Answer (score 0):

The issue we were having was that the `templateUrl` attribute was causing problems with our async data loading, so we removed the partial and added the template HTML into our parent partial.

The second issue was that we were using `src` instead of `ng-src`; the latter waits for any template values to be assigned before rewriting itself as the `src` attribute, thus preventing the 404s.